# Computation of a limit where De l'Hospital's rule yields no results

Tags: calculus, limits

I found out through Wolfram Alpha that

$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x\cdot e^{-ax^2} = 0$

for $a > 0$.

However, I'm not sure exactly how to verify this result myself. Trying to solve this through D.H. rule does not yield any tangible results:

$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x\cdot e^{-ax^2} = \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^{-ax^2}}{\frac{1}{x}} \overset{\text{D.H rule}}{=} \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(-2ax)e^{-ax^2}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}} = 2a\cdot \lim_{x\to+\infty} x^3 e^{-ax^2} $

And the process goes on, increasing the exponent $p$ of the polynomial coefficient $x^p$ by a step of 2 in every iteration. I'm wondering exactly how I can retrieve the result I noted on Wolfram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x}{e^{ax^2}} \overset{\text{L'Hopital}}{=} \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1}{2xae^{ax^2}}=0.$$

Comment: Well, that was embarassing. Any ideas on why one of two fractions would work instead of either?

Comment: @jason Because the derivative of x to a positive power 'simplifies', whereas the deravative of x to a negative power gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead using L'Hopital's rule on $$\frac{x}{e^{ax^2}}$$